# Initializing array members in for loop causes silent program termination?

Tags: c, winapi

When trying to initialize

```
charInfo[]
```

via a for loop of any amount of iterations (or any loop for that matter), the program terminates unexpectedly with no indication of why.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){

    //Create handle for screen buffer & pointer for accesing console cursor information
    HANDLE handleNewScreenBuffer;
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO *ConsoleCursorInfo;

    //Create rectangle & character info array to be drawn on screen
    SMALL_RECT rectangle = {0, 0, 64, 7};
    CHAR_INFO charInfo[520];
    COORD coordBufSize = {65, 8};
    COORD coordBufCoord = {0, 0};

    handleStandardOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUT_HANDLE);
    handleNewScreenBuffer = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    GetConsoleCursorInfo(handleNewScreenBuffer, ConsoleCursorInfo);
    ConsoleCursorInfo->bVisible = 0;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(handleNewScreenBuffer, ConsoleCursorInfo);


    // Write green background and red & to character info array 
    for (int x = 0; x < (sizeof(charInfo)/4); ++x){
        charInfo[x].Attributes = BACKGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED;
        charInfo[x].Char.AsciiChar = (char)'&';
    }


    WriteConsoleOutput(handleNewScreenBuffer, charInfo, coordBufSize, coordBufCoord, &rectangle);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(handleNewScreenBuffer);

    Sleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: When values are initialized manually, there is no issue and the program runs as expected. Here the first and last squares of the console window are initialized correctly.

```
charInfo[0].Attributes = BACKGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED;
charInfo[0].Char.AsciiChar = (char)'&';
charInfo[519].Attributes = BACKGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED;
charInfo[519].Char.AsciiChar = (char)'&';
```

Note: I also understand that this is an outdated way of doing things I'm just exploring a bit.

Do the arrays leave scope when entering a loop? That doesn't make any sense but I'm unsure of any other reason this could happen.

UPDATE: Upon further inspection it seems that the code above can be simplified by removing
`handleStandardOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUT_HANDLE);`
which resolves the issue.

Still begs the question of *why* establishing a handle to the output buffer (which is un-needed for right now anyway but I digress) causes such strange behavior.

Comment: `sizeof(charInfo)/4` --> `sizeof(charInfo)/sizeof(*charInfo)`

Comment: looks like `ConsoleCursorInfo` isn't initialized, so `ConsoleCursorInfo->` invokes undefined behavior ..? Please provide a [mre]. There's nothing wrong with the scope of `charInfo`

Comment: @yano I apologize, Where should I provide the minimal reproducible example?

Comment: In your question. Although I see now those are winapi calls, so you probably do have an mre, my apologies. However, `ConsoleCursorInfo` is assuredly uninitialized, so dereferencing it invokes undefined behavior. Whatever `GetConsoleCursorInfo` is using it for or doing to it, changes in that function won't persist outside of it. You probably want `CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO ConsoleCursorInfo;` then `GetConsoleCursorInfo(handleNewScreenBuffer, &ConsoleCursorInfo); ConsoleCursorInfo.bVisible = 0;`

Comment: See the edit above for the resolution! It seems that ```CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO``` being uninitialized was not the culprit.

Comment: Glad to hear you have got it working, but a couple of things 1) If you have an answer, please post it as an answer. Updating your original post with the solution is not how SO works. 2) Dereferencing an unintialized pointer like you are doing invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) meaning _anything_ can happen, including work as expected. That doesn't mean it isn't wrong. Any manner of things could cause the behavior to change, including different compiler, different compiler flags, run on different machine, etc. You always want to fix UB.

Comment: I don't know much about winapi, but your fix certainly seems fishy. `handleStandardOut` is unused, and should be removed, but unless `GetStdHandle` is doing more behind the scenes than meets the eye, simply removing that line shouldn't fix anything. This is exactly the type of symptom/observation that comes from UB. I'm also not saying the UB I pointed out is the _only_ problem.

Comment: I've made the changes to the post as you suggested. Please let me know if theres any other formatting errors I should fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `handleStandardOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUT_HANDLE);` resolves the issue. Inplying that as @yano says, the uninitialized `*CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO` pointer is causing unpredictability. By creating the `CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO` object and then creating the pointer to said object as `CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO *ConsoleCursorInfoPtr = &ConsoleCursorInfo;` the line `handleStandardOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUT_HANDLE);` can be added back in and behavior is normal.